# Rewind and Fast-Forward keys not working on Macbook Air

Tags: macos, keyboard, youtube, karabiner

The `rewind` (F7) and `fast-forward` (F9) keys are not working in youtube. I've got `Karabiner Elements` installed, which doesn't modify those keys and even if I disable `KE`, the keys won't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: YouTube just uses Left & Right arrows.

Comment: @Tetsujin I was hoping that I could control youtube in the background with the function keys